# Can't calculate compound interest correctly

Tags: python, math, tkinter

Here is the code:

```
def calculate(*args):
try:
    value = float(income.get())
    expenses.set("$"+str(value * .60))
    longTerm.set("$"+str(value * .10))
    vacation.set("$"+str(value * .04))
    carDown.set("$"+str(value * .04))
    homeDown.set("$"+str(value * .02))
    guiltFree.set("$"+str(value * .20))
    projection.set("$"+str(value * .10 * 1 + 0.05/4 ** 4*10))

except ValueError:
    pass
```

For some reason, the output when I pass in 100 is $100.001953125

What am I doing wrong in the projection.set section of code for the math?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but I you want to implement the formula

```
A = P(1+r/m)^mt
```

You would need

```
projection.set("$"+str(value * .10 *( 1 + 0.05/4) ** (4*10)))
```

rather than

```
projection.set("$"+str(value * .10 * 1 + 0.05/4 ** 4*10))
```

(Remember [PEMDAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics))

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you.

What I had before was very similar to what you put and I'm not exactly sure what you did differently, but it worked :)

Comment: I just added two pairs of parenthesis, one to make sure that it was all of `1+0.05/4` that was being raised to a power and not just `0.05/4`, and the other one to make sure that the power was all of `4*10` and not just `4`, with the result multiplied by `10`.